# Change color of previous command during runtime in c

Tags: c, terminal

I am trying to color a command that I enter to reflect the output of my program.

Say I input `pacman -Qe | grep "something"` I would like it to change color based upon if it returns any output. I have read about escape codes however I didn't find any way of changing color after a command has already been entered.

Comment: Use the ANSI codes to go back up and overwrite the previous command with the same, but with the coloration?